# Can every random variable be written as a Borel-measurable function of a uniformly distributed random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to find a proof for the claim that every random variable can be written as a Borel-measurable function of a uniformly distributed random variable. Can anyone point it out to me? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean every random variable or just every real-valued random variable?

Comment: If in this context the uniformly distributed random variable $U$ involved must satisfy $P(U\leq u)=u$ for $u\in(0,1)$ then the claim is not true. This because $X$ can be defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ that does not allow the existence of such $U$ (wich is bound to be defined on the same probability space) . Didn't you actually mean the claim that for any random variable $X$ we can find a measurable function $h$ such that $X$ and $h(U)$ have the same distribution? (So less demanding than $X=h(U)$)